# String to array node js javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Hi my current string is shown:

```
082759
078982
074470
066839
062069
062068
062029
062027
059304
059299
056449
056421
052458
050666
100530
078977
072967
072958
072957
066982
062864
062064
056506
052456
```

24 6 digit numbers in total, notice the new lines between them.
I need this entire string to be broken down into an array such that [082759,078982,etc] is displayed and so that when calling:

```
console.log(array[0])
```

will output:

```
082759
```

NOTE: The '\n' method does not seem to work and when re-calling it [when within an array], e.g array[0], it outputs all the numbers.

The variable under which this data is derived from comes via:

```
var currentSku = $(this).attr('data-productsku')
```

So if this j-query has a specific string type then its probably something to do with this?

Comment: First of all the string should be in a single variable!

Comment: All the string is in a single variable; I'm trying to put it into one line first then break it down into an array. `The traditional arr = s.split("\n")

console.log(arr[0])` wouldn't work

Comment: Can you create a snippet in StackOverflow, or a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem please? When I do `split` it seems to work fine...

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. {Whatever}'s solution should just work, if it doesn't then something else is wrong.

Comment: @RaajNadar [You don't need to leave such comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202109/flagging-look-at-my-answer-pls-comments).

Answer (score 1):

Because they have `'\n'` in-between, use `split()`

```js
let arr = str.split('\n')
console.log(arr[0]);
```

Comment: Logs the entire thing; this is the problem I had, so this method does not work

Comment: @3.14159265432 it all depends on how you store your string. You said the numbers are separated by the new line character (\n), thus `split('\n')` must work correctly. If it does not, then your code is different from what you stated and you haven't told us what exactly is different.

Comment: thats how it looks like when I log the variable that it's all stored in. This is all from a get request so I'm not fully sure.

Comment: @3.14159265432 Edit your answer and provide the string as it appears in the response, not after being formatted by the console.

Comment: Re-check question

Comment: @3.14159265432 your edit is pointless because I have no idea what `this` refers to and what `data-productsku` looks like.

Comment: @3.14159265432 Jquery does not have a specific string type, no. Can you please create an [mcve] so we can reproduce your issue please?

Comment: @Whatever view my other posts to see more background info about what the variables are referring to.

Comment: @3.14159265432 your question should provide enough information and context to allow anyone to answer it easily. Providing [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is essential.

Answer (score 0):

```
array.split(/\n/)
```

or

```
array.split(\n)
```

Comment: Or `array.split('\n')` which is the most common way it's written.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```js
var test = "082759 078982 074470 066839 062069 062068";

var arr = test.split(" ");
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[4]);
```

Tested code!

**Note: There should be a space in between each number.**

Next line solution is here

```js
var test = 
`082759
078982
074470
066839
062069
06206`;

var arr = test.split("\n");
console.log(arr[0]);
console.log(arr[4]);
```

Comment: But in OP's example they're separated by a new line not by a space

Comment: @user184994 he/she did not mention how the var is set.. if it is in separate line I will update

Comment: OP's question says: "notice the new lines between them. "

Answer (score 0):

If you're adding the digit on a new-line each time, you can use [`.split()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) method.

You have to pass the delimiter you want to split by; in your case, you use [`\n`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) as that's how new-lines are escaped in Javascript. This will create an array of data.

Using the code below you can do like so:

---

```js
let string = `082759
078982
074470
066839
062069
062068
062029
062027
059304
059299
056449
056421
052458
050666
100530
078977
072967
072958
072957
066982
062864
062064
056506
052456`;

let arr = string.split('\n');

console.log(arr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If splitting using `\n` doesn't work then it might be that your string is using a different style of line ending. You can try `\r` or `\r\n` for instance.